# Date format not same

Tags: java, parsing, date

Okay, here's the problem :

```
Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
date.setTime(new Date());

File fileVIPC = new File("VIP members class list.txt");
Scanner scV = new Scanner(fileVIP);
scV.useDelimiter(",");

if(!fileVIPC.exists())
  fileVIPC.createNewFile();

Scanner newVIP = new Scanner(fileVIPC);
newVIP.useDelimiter(",");
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
Date rCDate;
String rCExpiryDate;
rCExpiryDate = scV.next();              
rCDate = f.parse(rCExpiryDate);

int dateInt = Integer.valueOf(date.get(Calendar.YEAR));
                    dateInt += 1;
                    date.set(Calendar.YEAR,dateInt);

                    dateInt = Integer.valueOf(date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                    dateInt -= 1;
                    date.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,dateInt);

    date.set(Calendar.YEAR,dateInt);
    rCDate = date.getTime();
    bWriterRenewVIP.write(rCDate +",");
```

So, when I write into my txt file, it turns out to be like this `Aug 02 03:23:28 SGT 3` which I don't know why there is a 3 after I renew for 1 year, it should show 2016 or something else. Any add-on codes you need just tell me. Please help , thanks !!

Comment: Why should it not show `3` for the year? What year value did you use?

Comment: shouldn't it be 2016 if I renew it ? I don't know what I did wrong there.

Comment: You're calling `date.set(Calendar.YEAR,dateInt);` twice, the second time after `dateInt` is the modified day of month.

Comment: @ZoogieZork Yes I think so too, but the day is 2 and the year is 3, so it doesn't work like it says above.

Comment: "The year 3"? Who are your VIPs?

Comment: You're setting the year and the day of the month to the same values - why? Also, *please* format your source code - is that really how it looks in your editor?

Comment: Is there any other code between the last two calls to `date.set`?  Also, I recommend you use [Calendar.add()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add(int,%20int)) to modify your values.

Comment: Guys, its.. just a silly mistake, 2 same dateInt , thanks. Really can't see.

Comment: Also, wherefore do you parse `rCDate` the first time? I don't think you use the value allocated there, you just replace the value later with `date.getTime()`

Comment: @user3900009 I would recommend you don't write your solution in your question. Answer your own question and accept that answer is a better way to do.

Comment: @user3755692 I parse it just to avoid the maybe not initialize error, cause I don't know other way to initialize that variable. I'm quite weak in Java.

Comment: @user3900009 Then I would just say `rCDate = null;` instead of parsing something you don't use - this will not waste cpu and ram.